# sidekiq does not generate sidekiq.pid file on heroku, using with Redistogo

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, pid, sidekiq, redistogo

I've been struggling for two days with getting sidekiq work on heroku production environment. I've read all the available documentation about similar issues, and still haven't been able to produce a working solution, I'd really like some help!

After deploying on heroku, my app crashes and I get the following error stack trace:

```
2014-09-23T23:38:40.905093+00:00 app[worker.1]: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /app/tmp/pids/sidekiq.pid
2014-09-23T23:38:40.905122+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/bin/sidekiq:23:in `<main>'
2014-09-23T23:38:40.905119+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sidekiq-3.2.5/bin/sidekiq:7:in `<top (required)>'
2014-09-23T23:38:40.905117+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sidekiq-3.2.5/lib/sidekiq/cli.rb:347:in `write_pid'
2014-09-23T23:38:40.905115+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sidekiq-3.2.5/lib/sidekiq/cli.rb:347:in `open'
2014-09-23T23:38:40.905121+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/bin/sidekiq:23:in `load'
2014-09-23T23:38:40.905118+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sidekiq-3.2.5/lib/sidekiq/cli.rb:41:in `parse'
2014-09-23T23:38:40.905114+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sidekiq-3.2.5/lib/sidekiq/cli.rb:347:in `initialize'
2014-09-23T23:38:39.588001+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
```

First, sidekiq is working correctly on my local machine. I'm using heroku's REDISTOGO for redis, on local production, sidekiq have been pointed to the REDISTOGO correctly and running fine.

Second, according to the stack trace, especially this line `No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /app/tmp/pids/sidekiq.pid`; it leads me to think that for some reason `sidekiq.pid` file is not generated correctly when running on heroku. On local environment, the `sidekiq.pid` file is generated everytime I start the app in the `app/tmp/pids/` directory, and assigns a different `pid` number every time. I'm `guessing` that when running on heroku, `sidekiq` tried to read from this file yet could not find it.

Here is contents in my `Procfile`:

```
web: bundle exec rails server
worker: bundle exec sidekiq -C config/sidekiq.yml
```

Here is contents in my `config/sidekiq.yml`

```
---
:verbose: true
:pidfile: ./tmp/pids/sidekiq.pid
:concurrency: 25
# Set timeout to 8 on Heroku, longer if you manage your own systems.
:timeout: 8
:queues:
  - carrierwave
```

Here is contents in my `sidekiq.rb`

```
Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.redis = { :url => ENV['REDISTOGO_URL'], :namespace => "mynamespece"}
end

Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
    config.redis = { :url => ENV['REDISTOGO_URL'], :namespace => "mynamespece"}
end
```

Update `1`:

I'm using `carrierwave` and `carrierwave-backgrounder` in sync with `sidekiq`.

Comment: Why are you creating a pidfile at all?

Comment: @MikePerham Hey Mike, I know you are the author of sidekiq, I appreciate your attention to this matter! I wasn't using `pid` intentionally. I'm new to sidekiq and I thought that's the default behavior, because during my implementation I didn't run into any configuration that references `pid` anywhere. What would you suggest, am I doing anything wrong? Maybe not using pid is the optimal way to implement sidekiq? I didn't find too much documentation on the pid part.

Comment: @MikePerham on my local environment, everytime I use `foreman start`, I see the following lines:

`17:28:57 web.1    | started with pid 20788`
`17:28:57 worker.1 | started with pid 20789`

The pid number would be different every-time.

Comment: @MikePerham Sorry I forgot to mention this in my original post; I was using `carrierwave` and `carrierwave-backgrounder` with `sidekiq`; so maybe using `pid` was a decision made by implementation of `carrierwave`

Comment: Just remove the pidfile line in your Sidekiq.yml, that should fix it.

Comment: @MikePerham Thanks, removing the `pidfile` line in `sidekiq.yml` does fix the problem of `No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /app/tmp/pids/sidekiq.pid` error message; however, now when I run `foreman create` with `bundle exec sidekiq -C config/sidekiq.yml` in `Procfile`, in my local environment, the worker no longer pulls job from the queue. It was working previously, with the `pidfile` line in `sidekiq.yml`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This issue has been resolved by the following actions:

1) Thanks to @MikePerham for pointing me to the right direction, first I removed this line in my `sidekiq.yml` file:

```
:pidfile: ./tmp/pids/sidekiq.pid
```

2) Then, in my `Procfile`, I had to use the following line to replace the origin:

```
web: bundle exec rails server -p $PORT
worker: bundle exec sidekiq -C config/sidekiq.yml
```

Now sidekiq is working correctly with redistogo on heroku for me.

Comment: This worked like a freaking charm. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 14):

I found it useful to add the directory to the repository and re-deploy the application.

```
mkdir -p tmp/pids
touch tmp/pids/.gitkeep
git add -f tmp/pids/.gitkeep
git commit -m 'Keep tmp/pids directory in repo'
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 10):

It was fixed by making `pids` directory in `tmp` directory in root of project